# does Azure OpenAI have access to the same knowledge base as GPT web page

Tags: azure-openai, chat-gpt-4

When I run a query on chatGPT webpage to ask for the president of France in 2015 for example, the program queries a knowledge base on Azure.
When I run the same query using Azure OpenAI service (I know they use the same models), I know I can use my own knowledge base processed by Cognitive services.
My question is does Azure OpenAI also have access to chatGPT knowledge base?

Answer (score 0):

yes, "GPT3.5 turbo" is ChatGPT model in fact, it is ChatGPT turbo version.GPT-3.5 is the nickname for text-davinci-003.

ChatGPT - Dialogue fine-tuned, aimed at conversational experience. Release notes: https://help.openai.com/en/articles/6825453-chatgpt-release-notes

GPT-3.5 - Instruction fine-tuned for the completion.